# Webpack with babel-loader not emitting valid es5

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, webpack-2, vue-loader, babel-loader

I have a webpack config that is based off https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js
It uses vue-loader and babel-loader. The issue is I cannot get it to generate ES5 code so that it will work in the most broad range of clients.

If I use the ES2015 preset, `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` fails to minify the output because Uglify can only handle ES5 (not counting the harmony branch). The errors are similar to: `Unexpected token: punc (()` and occur in multiple files.

I can work around this by using `babili-webpack-plugin` which will minify the ES6 code but is very slow. However, when I deploy this code, I see errors being reported back saying `Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode` so I know they are older clients choking on ES6 code.

How can I get proper ES5 code output from **babel-loader**? I have tried multiple presets, with or without the `transform-runtime` plugin. Config below:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const globEntries = require('webpack-glob-entries');
const _ = require('lodash');
const path = require('path');
const BabiliPlugin = require("babili-webpack-plugin");

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

let entries;
if (env === 'production') {
  entries = globEntries('./src/**/vue/*.js');
} else {
  entries = _.mapValues(globEntries('./src/**/vue/*.js'), entry => [entry, 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true']);
}

module.exports = {
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    path: '/', ///no real path is required, just pass "/"
    publicPath: '/vue',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
          },
          // other vue-loader options go here
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Enable HMR
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
};

if (env === 'staging' || env === 'production') {
  //module.exports.devtool = env === 'staging' ? '#source-map' : false;
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
  module.exports.output.path = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/v1/parse/cloud/public/vue');
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: `"${env}"`,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
      },
    }),
    // new BabiliPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repo for your configuration?

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme I could provide a repo with my package.json and my webpack.config.js but code beyond that would be difficult.

Comment: Are you using a `.babelrc` file? (`vue-loader` will have `babel-loader` use that.) You might want to also use the `es2016` and `es2017` presets (or `env`).

Comment: @bzeaman I am not currently using a `.babelrc` file but I have tried it. My understanding is that anything that can be set in `.babelrc` can be set in `options:` instead. I was using `env` preset originally but by default it uses `latest` and then I still can't use Uglify or deploy to older browsers. Trying to specify envs that require es2015 get me back to the same place.

Comment: @emkman I have put my comment into a more extensive answer. You are correct in that the options can be set without `.babelrc`, but you're not providing options from when parsing **`.vue` files**, as `vue-loader` will use `.babelrc` *by default* for its Babel configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vue-loader` will process your `js` with `babel-loader` (if it's detected), and [uses `.babelrc` by default](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/es2015.html#configuring-babel-with-babelrc).

In your current setup you are *not* passing any options to Babel when it is used by `vue-loader` (meaning Babel uses no rules for your Vue files).

Either create `.babelrc` or specify the `js` loader by yourself for the `.vue` files to provide it with options:

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel?presets[]=es2015' // Pass parameters as options
    }
  }
}
```

The [`env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) preset for Babel [has an `uglify` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#optionstargets-uglify) that will fully compile to **ES5**. This preset is recommended practice to keep your environment up to date.

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    [ "env", { "uglify": true } ],
    "stage-1" // Or other presets not included with 'env' preset.
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

Instead of using preset `es2015` only, you might add `es2016` and `es2017`, as well as `stage-4`, `stage-3`, etc. to assure all your code is transformed, and not just the ES2015 parts.

Comment: You are right, my lack of `.babelrc` was an issue. I think I had incorrectly assumed that the output from `vue-loader` was then passed into `babel-loader` using my webpack options. I created a `.babelrc` combining your example and those from https://github.com/vuejs-templates/ and now it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with answer here already, but here is a solution that does not require a .babelrc file.  This answer works for a standalone webpack.config.js file.  I got this answer from taking a look under the hood of the laravel-mix library.

```
module: {
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders:{
                    js: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {                
                                    cacheDirectory: true,
                                    presets: [
                                        ['env', {
                                            'modules': false,
                                            'targets': {
                                                'browsers': ['> 2%'],
                                                uglify: true
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    ],
                                    plugins: [
                                        'transform-object-rest-spread',
                                        ['transform-runtime', {
                                            'polyfill': false,
                                            'helpers': false
                                        }]
                                    ]
                                }
                        },
                    }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        }

    ]
},
```

I spent the better part of a day reading up all these useless blogs omit the core concept that babel-loader has to be attached to the vue-loader.

Comment: Interesting. I was originally working on a similar approach but could never find the right syntax for passing the options into babel in the vue-loader. Thanks for sharing.