# how to have Vuex mapState with computed properties in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to learn `Vuex` and tried adding the mapState with local computed property in my `Vuejs 2.0` application on top of `Laravel 5.4`, now while adding so I'm getting following error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (379:32)

  377 |         },
  378 |         mapState({
> 379 |             contactStore: state => state.contactStore
      |                                 ^
  380 |         })
  381 |     }
  382 | }
```

Here is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Contact Name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Company Name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">City</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Mobile</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Type</th>
                        <th class="text-left">SubType</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Profile</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="(item, index) in tableFilter">
                        <td class="text-left"><a @click="showModal(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showContactModal">{{ item.first_name+' '+item.last_name }}</a></td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ item.company.name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ item.city }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ item.email }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ item.mobile }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left"><span class="badge badge-info">{{ item.company.type }}</span></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><span class="badge badge-info">{{ item.company.sub_type }}</span></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><span class="badge badge-info">{{ item.profile }}</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapState} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                id: '',
                search: '',
                model: []
            }
        },
        computed: {
            tableFilter: function () {
                const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase();
                if(this.model)
                {
                    return this.model.filter((item) =>
                        (item.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                            || (item.last_name !==null && item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                            || (item.company.name !==null && item.company.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                        );
                }
            },
            mapState({
                contactStore: state => state.contactStore
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to replace table filter computed property with the current contact_list state, how can I achieve this or I'm doing some mistake, even if I do `...mapState({})` it is showing me same type of error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (378:8)

  376 |             }
  377 |         },
> 378 |         ...mapState({
      |         ^
  379 |             contactStore: state => state.contactStore
  380 |         })
  381 |     }
```

what can be done guide me. Thanks

Comment: It should be `...mapState({ contactStore: state => state.contactStore })`. If you've tried that, what error does it give you?

Comment: @thanksd Added the same in the question, please see the updated question.

Comment: Are you sure you have support for the spread operator `...`? Are you using babel?

Comment: Ok I got it, I need to have `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` and then create a `.babelrc` file in your project directory `{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the babel is not working on your vue file.  The laravel-mix library should do this for you, but if you are manually configuring the file using a webpack.config.js file, you will have to attach a babel loader to the vue loader.

I answered this question on another thread...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581031/1718887